How can I change checkers pieces to move only horizontally and vertically?
I am a beginner level programmer trying to learn Python. I could not figure out how to change the values so I can restrict the pieces of checkers from moving diagonally. I want them to be able to move only horizontally and vertically.
My code is given and I think the problem is inside the _move_left where there are moves.update, but I have no idea how to fix it. I am watching a video about creating it but the guy didn't explain that well how the functions work (he is making pieces move diagonally).
def get_valid_moves(self, piece):
    moves = {}
    left = piece.col - 1
    right = piece.col + 1
    up = piece.row - 1
    down = piece.row + 1
    row = piece.row
    col = piece.col

    if piece.color == BLACK or piece.king:
        moves.update(self._move_left(row, max(row - 3, 1), -1, piece.color, left))
        moves.update(self._move_right(row, max(row - 3, 1), -1, piece.color, right))
        moves.update(self._move_up(col, max(col - 3, 1), -1, piece.color, up))

    if piece.color == BEIGE or piece.king:
        moves.update(self._move_left(row, min(row + 3, ROWS), 1, piece.color, left))
        moves.update(self._move_right(row, min(row + 3, ROWS), 1, piece.color, right))
        moves.update(self._move_down(col, min(col + 3, COLS), 1, piece.color, down))

    return moves


def _move_left(self, start, stop, step, color, left, skipped=[]):
    moves = {}
    last = []
    for r in range(start, stop, step):
        if left < 0:
            break

        current = self.board[r][left]
        if current == 0:
            if skipped and not last:
                break
            elif skipped:
                moves[(r, left)] = last + skipped
            else:
                moves[(r, left)] = last

            if last:
                if step == -1:
                    row = max(r - 3, 0)
                else:
                    row = min(r + 3, ROWS)
                moves.update(self._move_left(r + step, row, step, color, left - 1, skipped=last))
                moves.update(self._move_right(r + step, row, step, color, left + 1, skipped=last))
            break
        elif current.color == color:
            break
        else:
            last = [current]

        left -= 1
    return moves


Diagonal movement is if you update both row and col in one move. When you make sure only one of those can change the valueper turn, your stone can't move diagonal anymore

Because of I am beginner, I am having issues. Can you give me example on my code if possible ?
thank you.
